# How to make GPU use high performance settings instead of power saving? [Dual Graphics]

Tags: laptop, graphics-card, gpu

I have been struggling with this for a long time.

It seems like my laptop uses only 1 GPU. When I turn on GPU monitoring, it says that everything is running on power saving mode. I switch applications to high performance, but GPU is  still running on power saving mode while laptop is plugged in.

[image: picture of situation]

Comment: What makes you think your laptop has multiple GPUs?

Comment: Can you give us your laptop model and GPU models? What GPU monitoring program did you use?

Comment: I have ASUS X550DP, i have apu AMD A10 5750 quad core(Radeon HD 8650G is the graphic card in it) 2.5 ghz, and gpu AMD HD 8670 2GB. I used monitoring from AMD Catalyst driver.

Comment: Please present a screenshot that shows what makes you think your " GPU is still running on power saving mode while laptop is plugged in."

Answer (score 1):

Go to "Switchable Graphic Application Setting" (bottom of your screenshot)
Then change the setting of the apps that you want to use dedicate graphic to "High Performance"

Hit Apply

It should be running on dedicate graphic now.

[image: Switchable Graphic Application Setting]

Answer (score -1):

I know it sounds stupid, but have you tried checking your windows power plan (If your using Linux then same thing.). If it's set to Power Saver then that may be why your GPU is still in power saver mode. If it's on balanced or High performance, then check the advanced power settings of your current power plan in the Control panel>>Hardware and Sound>>Power Options and make sure that the discrete GPU is set to Maximum performance and not power saving. If all that fails then the only thing i can recommend is to uninstall and reinstall your drivers.

Answer (score -1):

The best thing you can do is to install the latest driver for your GPUs which turns out to be AMD Catalyst 15.11.1 at the time of this writing and make sure "AMD Dual Graphics" is ON, as well as "Switchable Graphics Global Settings" is set to Optimise Performance.

Unfortunately nothing else will work, unless you are willing to dive deep in the Windows registries or downgrage your APU, because your APU/iGPU/Power-Saving-GPU might be slightly better than your dGPU/High-Performance-GPU and by default it will be set as the default GPU. Only DirectX 10 & 11 applications will use your dGPU through Dual Graphics and not DirectX 9 or OpenGL, as you can see [here](https://support.hp.com/rs-en/document/c03048333). 
If you were lucky enough you may see an option in Dual Graphics settings to allow all applications to use the Dual Graphics as it follows:
[image: AMD Dual Graphics Settings]